# Any implementation of the options framework for hierarchical reinforcement learning?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

Does anyone know of an existing implementation of the options framework for hierarchical reinforcement learning as described in [Sutton, Precup, & Singh (1999) Between MDPs and semi-MDPs: A
framework for temporal abstraction in reinforcement learning. *Artificial
Intelligence 112*: 181–211](http://www-anw.cs.umass.edu/~barto/courses/cs687/Sutton-Precup-Singh-AIJ99.pdf)? The ideal implementation would be in Python, although anything would be useful.

Comment: I'm trying to search the same subject on the Internet and still have not found anything. Since you've been asked this question for 4 months, would you like to know if you've already found something?

Comment: @RenataOliveira please do not use answers for commenting the questions. Answers are meant to answering them.